# Hyperbolic motion in Rindler coordinates never crossing the origin

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, acceleration

When we have a constant proper acceleration with $a_{\mu}a^{\mu} = g^2$ in the $x^1$ direction of some inertial frame, then

$$t  = g^{-1}\sinh(g\tau),$$
$$x  = g^{-1}\cosh(g\tau)$$

and the world line is a hyperbola $x^2 - t^2 = g^{-2}$. Mathematically, when $t = 0$, we can thus never have $x = 0$ as well. What does this mean physically? Why can't the world line cross the origin?

Answer (score 1):

This just depends on where you choose the initial position. The trajectory with $x = g^{-1}(\cosh(g\tau)-2)$ also has constant acceleration but it does cross the origin. It's no different from the fact that if you throw a ball up in the air, there's a maximum height beyond which it will not go.

Answer (score 0):

For $0<|g|<\infty$, all your hyperbolic worldlines have asymptotes along the light-cone of the event $O=(0,0)$.

One implication is that none of your worldlines can send a signal to event $O$, and event $O$ can't send a signal to any of your hyperbolic worldlines.

Possibly interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates#The_Rindler_horizon